# The "Rails" way to submit an unspecified number of user inputs into params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, input, hidden-field

I am working in Rails to allow an administrator to endow fictional money to users. In my mind, there are the following steps:

- An administrator asks the DB for a list of users
- The administrator specifies the amount of money given to each user
- The DB adds the specified amount to each user's account and saves

I have a code that works but is inelegant. I was wondering what the correct "Rails" way to approach this scenario would be. Specifically, I am seeking your help on the following points:

1. How to elegantly process an indeterminate number of inputs from the user (currently, I generate the form using for loop on all users)
2. How to send variables used in one action to another (currently, I am using the hidden_field_tag, but I find it a bit cumbersome)
3. Whether there is a way to avoid calling .to_i, .to_s, .to_f (since it seems quite unnecessary)
4. How to maximize performance by reducing unnecessary db query
   (currently, I am storing the size of users in @size)

My most important questions are #1 and #2. I would appreciate any hint / help. Thank you very much!

```
#This the action in the controller corresponds to the first bullet point 
def index
    @users = User.all
    @size = @users.length
end

#This the action in the controller corresponds to the third bullet point
def provide_currency
    array = *(1..params[:size])
    for i in array
        user = User.find(i)
        user.money += params[i.to_s].to_f
        user.save
    end
    redirect_to admin_path
end

#This is the index.html.erb that corresponds to the second bullet point
<%= form_tag provide_currency_path do %>
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>New endowment</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% for user in @users %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.name%></td>
        <td><%= user.email%></td>  
        <td>
            <%= number_field_tag (user.id) %>
        </td>     
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<%= hidden_field_tag "size", @size %>
<%= submit_tag "Provide", :class => "btn" %>
<% end %>
```